# JavaScript: Is there a benefit in using the charCode when comparing characters?

Tags: javascript, performance

First of all: I'm a bit into JavaScript but not much.

Today I saw these code:

```
if (stringToSearch[i].charCodeAt(0) === codeToSearch) {
```

The charCodeAt() method of String is used for to compare the current char with the searched char.

The full code of the function here:

```js
function getOccurences (stringToSearch, charToSearch) {
  var ret = 0;
  var codeToSearch = 0;
  var i;
  
  stringToSearch = stringToSearch.toUpperCase();
  codeToSearch = charToSearch.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);

  for (i = 0; i < stringToSearch.length; i++) {
    if (stringToSearch[i].charCodeAt(0) === codeToSearch) {
      ret++;
    }
  }
  
  return ret;
}
```

I would have compared the char directly. Without using charCodeAt().

Just ...

```
  stringToSearch[i] === charToSeach
```

As far as I know the computer compares just numbers anyway. Translates the characters to their UTF-codes. Subtracts these numbers against each other and then checks if the result has become zero.

So therefore my question:

**Does the usage of charCodeAt() makes any sense?**

**Are there a benefit to favor the direct charCode-comparison over the character-comparison.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`charCode` benefits when we have to increment/decrement the characters.
eg. if we have charCode('a') in variable x, then we can increment it using x++.
But if we had saved 'a' then we cannot perform arithmetic operations.
So `charCodeAt(number)` is used when you need to increment/decrement the characters.

Comment: Just thought: But wouldn't it be possible to use String[ indexNumber ] for the same reason? One can to upwards / downwards through a string by that the same.

Answer (score 3):

My intuition is to say there's a performance *hit* when you go through type-conversion and function-calling hoops like that.

That said, you'll likely eke out more performance out of the code by delegating to the native string methods, with something like:

```
function countCaseInsensitiveOccurrences(haystack, char) {
  haystack = haystack.toUpperCase();
  char = char.toUpperCase()[0];
  var count = 0, pos = -1;
  while ((pos = haystack.indexOf(char, pos + 1)) !== -1) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` will start traversing the string from the very beginning each time the loop is executed... so `O(n^2)` :-(

Comment: @mb21 I doubt it will if you pass the start index parameter.

Comment: right! I missed the second parameter... nice!